# Where is the helper function flask.helpers.total_seconds() useful for?

Tags: python, flask

I just get started to read the source code of Flask. I found there is a helper function which can be imported as below:

```
from flask.helpers import total_seconds
```

It's source code:

```
def total_seconds(td):
    """Returns the total seconds from a timedelta object.

    :param timedelta td: the timedelta to be converted in seconds

    :returns: number of seconds
    :rtype: int
    """
    return td.days * 60 * 60 * 24 + td.seconds
```

My question is, if I ever had a `timedelta` object, why do not just to get the total seconds via `td.total_seconds()` (provided by Python standard library) instead of using `total_seconds(td)` (provided by Flask)?

Comment: I don't see any use, except perhaps to have an integer (although casting would be much simpler), or perhaps it was written in a Python version that didn't have that method. You might want to write a PR to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timedelta` didn't gain a `total_seconds` method until Python 2.7. Until very recently, Flask still supported Python 2.6.

The functions that use Flask's `total_seconds` expect an `int` back, but `timedelta.total_seconds` returns a `float`. Internally, [`timedelta` is doing similar math](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c4b695f85e141f57d22d8edf7bc2c756da136918/Lib/datetime.py#L599-L602) to Flask, except accounting for microseconds as well by doing some extra multiplication and division.

Rather than deal with precision that it didn't need (and to support old versions), Flask implemented the function itself.

```
# Python's implementation, plus int()
int(((self.days * 86400 + self.seconds) * 10**6 + self.microseconds) / 10**6)

# Flask's implementation
td.days * 60 * 60 * 24 + td.seconds
```

Timing results:

```
td = timedelta(days=2, seconds=47, microseconds=753)

timeit int(td.total_seconds())
277 ns ± 6.55 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

timeit total_seconds(td)
197 ns ± 2.96 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```